# justifyContent: 'space-around' doesn't have margin in React Native

Tags: react-native, flexbox

I am new to React Native and working on an Open source project called [ReactNativeWeather](https://github.com/JakeLin/ReactNativeWeather)

I have put four `ForecastView` in one row like

```
<View style={styles.forecastContainer}>
  <ForecastView style={styles.forecast}/>
  <ForecastView style={styles.forecast}/>
  <ForecastView style={styles.forecast}/>
  <ForecastView style={styles.forecast}/>
</View>
```

I try to align all ForecastView in one row with some margins. like

[image]

This screenshot is from another open source project [SwiftWeather](https://github.com/JakeLin/SwiftWeather)

But in [ReactNativeWeather](https://github.com/JakeLin/ReactNativeWeather), it looks like 
[image]

Here are the styles

```
  forecastContainer: {
    flex: 1,
    flexDirection: 'row',
    justifyContent: 'space-around'
  },
  forecast: {
    flex: 1
  }
```

I think `justifyContent: 'space-around'` should do the job, but don't why it doesn't. Could you please give me some hint?

The code is on https://github.com/JakeLin/ReactNativeWeather can check out commit `0ccf4abb879656ab785814f01581121b60fc3b3a`

Thanks

Comment: forecastContainer has a `flex` property so that means it's nested within another flex container. A nested flex-container may be problematic especially with custom elements. Have you tried `justify-content: space-between` and `margin: 0 auto 0 0;` for the right side flex-item and `margin: 0 0 0 auto;` for the left side flex-item?

Comment: @zer00ne thanks, `forecastContainer` is in another container, I have tried `space-between`, it doesn't work either. There is not `margin: 0 auto 0 0;` in React Native. I tried to apply `margin:100` in `forecast` before, still doesn't work. Here is the code https://github.com/JakeLin/ReactNativeWeather/blob/master/src/WeatherView.js ,

Comment: display:flex; seems missing in the rule .forecastContainer ...

Comment: okay i see it is not missing , thanks you for sharing this with us https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/flexbox.html

Answer (score 4):

I have fixed it by specifying the `width`

```
const { width, height } = Dimensions.get('window');
  forecastContainer: {
    paddingTop: 80,
    width: width,
    flexDirection: 'row',
    justifyContent: 'space-around',
  },
```

here is the solution in Github https://github.com/JakeLin/ReactNativeWeather/blob/57e37946c4e6bf655d0660e0cf5e0bdb38fe358d/src/WeatherView-styles.js#L36